# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Instances

Tags: java, classification, weka

I'm trying to build a classifier using weka, so my aim is to loop through my data and call `classifyInstances` on each instance. Then compare the predicted class value to the actual class value. Count the number of correct predictions, and print out the accuracy of the classifier over the test data.

```
public class testMachine{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String arff = "C:/Users/Emil/Downloads/Week 1/Arsenal_TRAIN1.arff";
    Instances data = DatasetLoading.loadData(arff);
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);

NaiveBayes classifier = null;
classifier.buildClassifier(data);

double[] s = new double[0];

for(int i=0; i<data.numAttributes();i++) {
classifier.classifyInstance(data[i]);//error is here
    
}
}
```

Though I get the following error and would like some help on how to proceed from here:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Instances

Answer (score 2):

Instances is a collection class, not an array, you cannot use brackets to get the element.

Replace

```
classifier.classifyInstance(data[i]);
```

with

```
classifier.classifyInstance(data.get(i));
```